# Illegal access to Core Data context: what thread is the owner of the context provided in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I have a class with a method like this:

```
- (void)getEntities
{
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

   NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
   NSArray *entities = [mainContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

   for (NSManagedObject *item in entities) {
      NSLog(@"Name: %@", ((MyEntity *)item).name);
   }
}
```

I have enabled the `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` and when I call this method (in main thread) I get the error:

> CoreData: error: The current thread is not the recognized owner of this NSManagedObjectContext(0x16d40160).  Illegal access during executeFetchRequest:error:

However, if I do:

```
- (void)getEntities
{
   NSManagedObjectContext *privateContext = [CoreDataStack getPrivateContext];

   if (privateContext != nil) {
       [privateContext performBlock: ^{
           NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
          NSArray *entities = [privateContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

          for (NSManagedObject *item in entities) {
             NSLog(@"Name: %@", ((MyEntity *)item).name);
          }
      }];
   }
}
```

And I call it also in main thread, it does not seem to cause such Core Data error... why? I've been always assuming that the `NSManagedObjectContext` provided by default in `AppDelegate` and I'm retrieving belongs to main thread... What I'm doing wrong or missing?

The entities I'm trying to fetch using the context from `AppDelegate` where previously saved from a context that was created in a private queue (similar to the one I create in my second code snippet). Could that be the cause of the error? Such private context was not a child of any other context, and I had no error when saving it.

I need to get the entities I have already stored by using a private context in the main thread, to keep them in an `NSArray` in the implementation of an `UIViewController`.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What is your first usage of that context? Is everything from the main thread? What exactly is the code you have for the context creation?

Comment: Are you sure you're always calling that method on the main thread?

Comment: @Wain I was certainly calling the context in `AppDelegate` the first time from a thread that wasn't the main one, so that seemed to be the problem, thanks.

Comment: @TomHarrington I was always calling that method on main thread, but I wasn't initializing the context on such thread, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem wasn't in the method but my initialization of the context in `AppDelegate`: before calling the method in the question,  and in certain scenario I was retrieving the context the first time from a queue that wasn't the main thread, and that seemed to be causing the context to be initialized in that other queue.